# Camel route does not log when deployed in ServiceMix

Tags: apache-camel, log4j, apache-servicemix

I referred below article and created dependencies and log4j properties 
http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j.html

Here is my simple route

```
from("direct:start")
    .routeId("LogEipInfoLevelRoute")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Displaying Something - ${body}")
    .to("mock:result");
```

Once i deploy my route in servicemix, im checking service mix log. I couldnt find any such message logged. except the route creation message with specified id.

Am i checking it in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using OSGI Based ServiceMix version

Please execute following command in karaf console:

```
karaf@root> log:display | grep Displaying
```

More about ServiceMix logging systems can be found under http://servicemix.apache.org/docs/4.4.x/users-guide/logging-system.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to send a message to the `direct:start` endpoint for anyting to happen.

If you just want to see something going on, then you can use a timer instead of direct, eg

```
from("timer:foo?period=5000")
```

to figure a new message every 5 seconds. Notice the message body is `null` from a timer.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It worked.   Currently logs are displayed in servicemix.log file. If i want to print messages in different file logs based on my camel route requirement, How do i do it?

Comment: Read about logging in Karaf -> https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.2.x/users-guide/logging-system.html

Answer (score 1):

You must pass something to direct:start for something to happen.  You can read more here about using direct : http://camel.apache.org/direct.html

I would just suggest using a timer to kick off your route.  Once your route is kicked off by the timer your log will be written out to your log file.